# How to call two endpoints in a WSO2 ESB application but only call the second should the first not fail or have a connection refused?

Tags: xml, wso2, vfs, wso2-esb

I have an application that sends a file to an endpoint. I want to update that application to send the same file to a second endpoint only if the first one succeeds. This will serve as a confirmation file that the first endpoint was reached directly.

How do I ensure if I have two endpoints that the second is not called should there be any errors with sending the file to the first such as a connection refused error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter mediator to check the backend response code. Here in the following sample I have check the HTTP status code and only if it is 200 the second endpoint is invoked. Depending on your backend you can change the desired response code. The filter mediator is very similar to the java if-else condition and you can refer to the documentation [1] to further clarification. Here I have added a payload factory mediator to create an error response in case of failure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="file_upload"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Invoking " value="First backend"/>
         </log>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <http uri-template="http://run.mocky.io/v3/61ebc934-5719-4cc6-8347-f121f18d9f37"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <filter regex="200" source="$axis2:HTTP_SC">
            <then>
               <log level="custom">
                  <property name="Invoking " value="Second backend"/>
               </log>
               <call>
                  <endpoint>
                     <http uri-template="http://run.mocky.io/v3/49f40df3-bb95-4f43-94fe-282fd72325ec"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </call>
            </then>
            <else>
               <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                  <format>{"Backend":"$1","Response code":"$2"}</format>
                  <args>
                     <arg value="Failute"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$axis2:HTTP_SC"/>
                  </args>
               </payloadFactory>
            </else>
         </filter>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/Filter+Mediator

**UPdated**

There should be a mechanism for the ESB to identify if the file is uploaded successfully. If it is not possible to check that you have no way of verifying if the file was uploaded successfully. But you want to check for issues such as connection timeout you can define a responseAction [2] for the endpoint as fault. If there is any issue while conneting to the endpoint it will invoke the fault sequence defined in the proxy service.

```
<timeout>
            <duration>timeout duration in seconds</duration>
            <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
</timeout>
```

[2]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Endpoint+Error+Handling

Comment: I see, but this is specific to calling an API that will have a response correct? In my case its sending a file to a folder on a remote system and I want the second endpoint to not be called if that file file fails to send to the remote system specified in the first endpoint.

Is it possible to do that with the filter mediator as well?

Comment: This expects a response code during a successful invocation. When you upload the file to the remote system, does it send a response code during a successful or a failure scenario

Comment: There is no response from the remote system upon success or failure. What I have noticed happens is that I have a ActionAfterFailure and ActionAfterProcess both set to move the file to respective folders afterwards but im noticing that regardless of the Connection refused error when sending the file, the ESB application will send it to the folder specified in ActionAfterProcess even though I would expect it to be in the folder set for ActionAfterFailure. I tried this as an alternative to the second endpoint as I found that in the same scenario it will send to both endpoints.

Comment: AFAIK the ActionAfterFailure is used only if there is any issue while processing the message inside the ESB. Since there is no response code there is no way for the ESB to know if the file upload process is successful. If there is no response code you can make another call after the file upload to check if the file exists in that location.

Comment: Ok how would I call the same endpoint I uploaded the file to in order to check if a file exists and then only if it does call a separate endpoint to put the file in that second location as well?